# addinfourl instance has no attribute 'getcode' - Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, urllib

I have python 2.7.3 on my machine and when I run the following code, it runs just fine.

```
response = urllib.urlopen(myUrl, params)
if response.getcode() != 200 and response.getcode() != 204:
    print "response status:", \
    response.getcode(), response.read()
```

However when my colleague is trying to run my script, he gets the following error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'getcode'
```

He has python 2.7.5. Most of the answers recommend using urllib2. But I don't really want to use it as it will lead to a lot of code change. Is this due to the python version difference, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it's a version issue. It works for me in version 2.7.3 (Debian) but not 2.4 (CentOS). Both cases using urllib2.

I get the same error about "addfourl".

Comment: It might be platform specific as well. I got this error on version 2.7.5 on redhat. On ubuntu, it runs just fine with both 2.7.3 and 2.7.5